# How to display updated field in MySQL in new textarea in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL Database where the users can create a `ticket` then update the ticket if need be.  This all works and the user can view the updated field in the , but what I would to achieve is to display the newly updated field in a different textarea field but not be able to edit it and only edit a new textarea field.  Once saved and the user needs to update it again it needs to then display the 2 uneditable textfields and display new textfield to update.

Here is my code what i have at the moment:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 <?php echo (!empty($description_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
<label>Description</label>
<textarea name="descriptionfield" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Enter Description"><?php echo $description; ?></textarea>
</div>
```

So with this code I can update and delete but only displays in the same textarea.

Can someone point me in the right direction to achieve this?
Hoping what I explained makes sense.

Thanks

Something like the below image

[image: something like this]

Comment: What code you provide is not of any help. Once updated the database, to show the New result, you should reload the page, the usual way, or through Ajax. Get back with more details, I might help.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.  I have updated my question with an image to try and explain things better.

Comment: @Allrounder your code does not help even now. I does not convey whether you are trying to add additional textareas on reload or through jQuery/Ajax. Please add all the relevant information here for someone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are only able to update and delete a textarea but you want to show the original one and a new empty text area after they submit, then if they update that one, the original one and second one show all while allowing a new textfield to be there?

You aren't creating the text-boxes, submitting queries, and fetching results in a way the allows you to do that.

What you need to do is:

1. In your general application you will need 2 things, the empty text area field for the which you already have. An empty div area where you could display the old text areas.
2. In your database you need to add another table because you you will basically be joining these child text area updates updates. new table: textareachildren.
3. When somebody submits a ticket, that text area information should go into your first table where the info is going which is already happening. Now I'm assuming your table for those posts has a primary ID correct? so lets say we just put a ticket in and the ID is 1. Here is where @Padmanabhan is trying to find out, when the ticket is submitted the page is refreshed correct? and it shows that ticket they just submitted?
4. Now they want to edit that ticket's text area, I assume you already are pulling in the ticket by it's ID. Since you said they could already edit/update but it just shows the value they submitted. It looks by your picture that theres a note added and new note section. OK so thats good, so within that function where they could update the ticket text area field, a few important things need to happen. Once they click update, you need to run a sql query to input this new textarea value into the textareachildren table. within that table there should be 3 columns, the primary ID of the new items in there, the value of the textarea field, and third the important the connecting_ID which is the same value of the ID of the original ticket ID. this is how they will be connected and you could display those historical text areas.
5. Now go back to your original query that displays the ticket when they first submit, in there you need to also query by joining the the original ticket id with the connecting_ID of the new child textarea. The query will say ah yes, I am pulling this textarea value from the other table because my connecting_ID is 1 and it matches my 'parents' so I know I belong to them. Then just display that in the html within a new text area field that does not have the option to update/edit, since its probably a for loop for all those children that you want to show, you could add in the HTML textarea disabled readonly attributes, and even add classes to it so its like grayed out or something that shows you can't edit.

So to summarize every time somebody updates the text field you aren't changing that original value since you want to display that, you just add this new child textarea field value in a new table, when you query to show those old values to you just join them and display those historical textareas how ever you want.

Comment: Thanks,  That is exactly what I am looking for.   I will work on the code and see if I can get it to work.  This is the first time I am doing this, so let's hope I get it right :-)

Comment: Thanks.  If I don't come right, I will try and find a tutorial on what I would like to do.

Comment: @ Gianni I am struggling a bit here with this.  Is there a tutorial which i can follow?

Comment: @Allrounder which part are you stuck in?